# Highlight One Row of a Table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

Hello good people of StackOverflow,

Apologies in advance for how monumentally stupid I am being, but I need your help.

I have a table which is generated by an SQL query and the user needs to be able to select one row, which passes a value into a hidden text box. This bit I have managed to do OK, but I need to show which row they have selected, and if they change their mind and then select a different row, only the new row is highlighted.

I know this should be pretty basic, but I can't work out the logic. So far I have this:

```
function getOLBC(olbc)
{
    document.getElementById("ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.1.").value=olbc;
    var rows = document.getElementById("results").getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
    for (var i =0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        var answer = document.getElementById("ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.1.").value
        if (answer = olbc)
        {
            document.getElementById(olbc).style.background="red";
            document.getElementById(olbc).style.color="white";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById(olbc).style.background="white";
        }
    }
}
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
    <tr class="unselected" id="AL-AAA98"onclick="getOLBC('AL-AAA98')"><td class="OLBC">AL-AAA98</td><td>AAAL</td><td>Grade A in Economics<br />Grade A in Mathematics<br />Grade A in Business Studies</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="unselected" id="AL-AAA77"onclick="getOLBC('AL-AAA77')"><td class="OLBC">AL-AAA77</td><td>AAAL</td><td>Grade A in Economics<br />Grade A in Mathematics<br />Grade A in Spanish</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="unselected" id="AL-AAA42"onclick="getOLBC('AL-AAA42')"><td class="OLBC">AL-AAA42</td><td>A*AAL</td><td>Grade A in Mathematics<br />Grade A in Human Biology<br />Grade A in Physics</td><td></td></tr>
```

Can anyone help? Apologies for the n00bish-ness of this question.

Thanks!

Comment: 1st of all: if (answer = olbc), you are assigning olbc value to answer, rather than comparing the two. use a double equal

Comment: you assign olbc to answer in this line `if (answer = olbc)`.

Comment: also, it doesn't appear that anything is changing within the loop? like its going to do the same exact thing every iteration.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that too, but I wasn't sure how to structure to say "if there is one row that is already selected, then change the colour back to the original and change the colour of this row instead."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for... I removed the onclick dom element (better to separate the js from the dom).

with jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/cr1urhv6/

```
$("#myTable tr").click(function(e) {
  $("#myTable tr").removeClass("highlight");
  $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

or with pure js: http://jsfiddle.net/cr1urhv6/1/

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tr");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        [].forEach.call(rows, function(el) {
            el.classList.remove("highlight");
            });
        this.className += ' highlight';
    }, false);
}
```

This is removing any current highlighting... and then adding the highlight class to the TR we clicked within.

Answer (score 1):

try doing

```
if (answer == olbc)
```

instead of

```
if (answer = olbc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually tinkered enough to find my own solution too, which perhaps isn't as elegant as Smerny's answer but here it is:

```
    function getOLBC(olbc){
    var selectedCount = document.getElementsByClassName("selected").length;

    if (selectedCount <= 0)
        {
        document.getElementById("ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.1.").value=olbc;
        document.getElementById(olbc).className="selected"
        }
    else 
        {
        var selectedRow = document.getElementsByClassName("selected")[0].id
        document.getElementById(selectedRow).className="deselected";
        document.getElementById("ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.1.").value=olbc;
        document.getElementById(olbc).className="selected"
        }
```